# Unable to configure MaxMindDB's Apache module

Tags: apache-2.2, httpd.conf, geoip

I recently installed MaxMind's MaxMindDB apache module successfully.

I added a new file called `geoip.conf` to `/etc/httpd/conf.d/` with the following contents:

```
<IfModule mod_maxminddb.c>
    MaxMindDBEnable On
    MaxMindDBFile COUNTRY_DB /some/dir/GeoLite2-Country.mmdb
    MaxMindDBEnv MM_COUNTRY COUNTRY_DB/country/iso_code

    SetEnvIf MM_COUNTRY US AllowUS
    Deny from all
    Allow from env=AllowUS
</IfModule>
```

When running `apachectl -t` I get the following error:

```
Syntax error on line 11 of /etc/httpd/conf.d/geoip.conf:
deny not allowed here
```

When I commented out the "Deny from all" line I got a similar error stating that `allow not allowed here`

I was unable to find anything online as this module has little documentation. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: #Geo Restrict
                MaxMindDBEnable On
#               MaxMindDBFile DB /path/to/GeoIP/GeoLite2-Country.mmdb
                MaxMindDBFile DB /root/GeoIP/GeoIP.dat
                MaxMindDBEnv MM_COUNTRY_CODE DB/country/iso_code

                SetEnvIf MM_COUNTRY_CODE ^(RU|DE|FR|US|CN) BlockCountry
                Deny from env=BlockCountry
How to enable this module

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is simply because your `Deny` and `Allow` need to be applied within a container, either a `<Directory>`, `<Files>` or `<Location>` section.